# Some Questions about QMediaPlayer() in PyQt6

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm trying to play sound with `QMediaPlayer()`

**Code 1**: this work fine.

```py
import sys

from PyQt6.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt6.QtMultimedia import QAudioOutput, QMediaPlayer
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication

app = QApplication([])

filename = "src/2.mp3"
player = QMediaPlayer()
audio_output = QAudioOutput()
player.setAudioOutput(audio_output)
player.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename))
audio_output.setVolume(50)
player.play()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**Code 2** but this have no voice.

```py
import sys

from PyQt6.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt6.QtMultimedia import QAudioOutput, QMediaPlayer
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication

app = QApplication([])

def play_it():
    filename = "src/2.mp3"
    player = QMediaPlayer()
    audio_output = QAudioOutput()
    player.setAudioOutput(audio_output)
    player.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename))
    audio_output.setVolume(50)
    player.play()

play_it()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I can't find what make differences here. Thanks for your help sincerely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the `player.play()` method is called it exits the function and the media player is garbage collected. You will need to keep a reference to the `player` by returning it if you would like it to live beyond the scope of the function call.

for example:

```
import sys

from PyQt6.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt6.QtMultimedia import QAudioOutput, QMediaPlayer
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication

app = QApplication([])

def play_it():
    filename = "src/2.mp3"
    player = QMediaPlayer()
    audio_output = QAudioOutput()
    player.setAudioOutput(audio_output)
    player.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename))
    audio_output.setVolume(50)
    return player

player = play_it()
player.play()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```